# Widget Select Options not saving

Tags: widgets

I have a widget where there is a select dropdown, with a list of all the pages on the site. I am trying to get my code correct so that when a user chooses a page, after clicking Save in the widget, the select box doesn't revert back to 'Select a page' value.

This is the snippet I have now but it's not working correctly. There are no errors being displayed either. Any help would be welcome. Thanks

```
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('read_more_link'); ?>"><?php _e('Read More Link', 'iw_widget_plugin'); ?></label>

<select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('read_more_link'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('read_more_link'); ?>" class="widefat">

    <option value="Select A Page">
        <?php echo esc_attr( __('Select A Page') ); ?>
    </option>
    <?php
        $pages = get_pages();
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
           echo '<option value="' . get_page_link($page->ID) . '" id="' . $page->post_title . '"', $read_more_link == $page ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $page->post_title, '</option>';
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

Comment: When you inspect the HTML after saving, does the option that is *supposed* to be selected have the `selected="selected"` attribute?  (I suspect that the evaluation of `$read_more_link == $page ? ' selected="selected"' : ''` isn't working the way you think it should).

Comment: Also I think that code have some error. Why you're adding '$' sign before the get_page_link() function?

Comment: I've removed the '$' from in front of get_page_link(), thanks for spotting that.

Comment: To answer @JaredCobb; When I select a page from the dropdown list, I then click Save, and it reverts back to the default Select A Page. Looking at the code using Dev Tools, there is no 'selected' code added.

Comment: modify the code little bit. I think that it will work `( ($read_more_link == get_page_link($page->ID) ) ? ' selected="selected"' : '')`

Comment: Sorry, that didn't make a difference.

Comment: how to storing the value of selected item in $read_more_link variable?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Store the variable, yes, but then I'd need to alter the code in other places which I am not sure of.

Comment: `get_field_id()` and `get_field_name()` are plugin (or whatever) functions and not core. Please ask at their support forum as it's off topic here.